# Ebay API - How To Determine Shipping Locations From FindItemsByCategory?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm retrieving all used buy-it-now camera and lenses from

EBAY-AT, EBAY-CH, EBAY-DE, EBAY-ES, EBAY-FR, EBAY-FRBE, EBAY-GB, EBAY-IE, EBAY-IT, EBAY-NL, EBAY-NLBE, EBAY-PL and EBAY-US

My 'customers' will come from all over Europe and the United States

I want to show them products which offer delivery to their country regardless of which EBAY site it originates.

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByCategory.html#findItemsByCategory

shipToLocations - An international location or region to which the seller is willing to ship the item. Only returned when the seller has specifically identified locations where she is willing to ship the given item. specified.

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/Enums/shipToLocationList.html

This lists the possible values for the shipToLocation

However the API calls **all** come back with 'Worldwide' for shipToLocation, however this is just not true as I checked some which say are ship to just UK, Europe or even collection only.

What other options are there?

Comment: Well if they all ship worldwide, then what’s the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - they all say 'Worldwide' but that's wrong. Will edit

Comment: Well I suppose that’s a problem with their API then. Not loads you can do about that if you wanted to carry on using the API, other than flag it as an issue with them. You could build a web scraper instead that takes the info from the website.

Comment: I scripted a web scraper before I moved to the API, but that's category page only level and I can't get any shipping data off their category pages. I retrieve about 37,000 results just for UK. 

I suppose I could web scrape though, UK has about 2000 new items per day - and I could just scrape the newly inserted.

Comment: You could still get most product info using the API, but use a web scraper to go to the URL of each product and check shipping location

Comment: Thanks, that will now indeed be my back up plan.